# How to resolve multiple join with LinQ?

Tags: c#, linq, join

So, let's say I have a `Contest` that can have multiple `ContestCulture`.
For this contest, I must have `Documents` , which have a `DocumentType` and a `Culture` (Rules, TermsAndConditions, PrivacyPolicy)

For each `ContestCulture`, I must have AT LEAST one `Document` for each `DocumentType` in order for the `Contest` to be valid.

So let's say I have a `Contest` with 2 `ContestCulture` (fr-CA, en-CA)
I must have AT LEAST 6 `Document` for that `Contest`

- Document1 : Culture1, Rules
- Document2 : Culture1, TermsAndConditions
- Document3 : Culture1, PrivacyPolicy
- Document4 : Culture2, Rules
- Document5 : Culture2, TermsAndConditions
- Document6 : Culture2, PrivacyPolicy

Entities are like following :

```
public class Document
{
    public DocumentType DocumentType { get; set; }
    public int CultureId { get; set; }
    public Culture Culture { get; set; }
    public int ContestId { get; set; }
    public Contest Contest { get; set; }
    //Some other properties
    //...
}

public class Contest
{
    public List<Document> Documents { get; set; }
    public List<ContestCulture> ContestCultures { get; set; }
    //Some other properties
    //...

}

public class ContestCulture 
{
     public int ContestId { get; set; }
    public Contest Contest { get; set; }

    public int CultureId { get; set; }
    public Culture Culture { get; set; }

    //Some other properties
    //...
}

public class Culture
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now that the context is set..

I have 3 lists :

- a list of `DocumentType` (list of `enum` values)
- a list of `ContestCulture` Ids (list of `int`)
- a list of `Documents` for the `Contest` (list of `Document`)

How can I check if I have at least 1 `Document` for each `DocumentType` for each `ContestCulture` ?

I'm really new to LinQ so I tried this :

```
from cultureId in list_usedCultureIdsForContest
join doc in documents on cultureId equals doc.CultureId into temp1
from t in temp1.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {cultureId, t};
```

but it only gives me the ones I have, like shown below :
[image]

Comment: Sounds confusing to me. So the relationship between 3 lists is: 1 Contest can have many ContestCultures, 1 Contest can have many Documents. Is it correct? And 1 Contest is VALID only when ALL document type exists. What is that related to Culture?

Comment: @Alex-TinLe Hi there ! you're right with the relationship between Contest, ContestCulture and Document. The Contest is VALID when ALL DocumentType exists for each ContestCulture. In my Example, CultureId representstThe ContestCulture.Id

Comment: I will edit the OP because it's a bit confusing. I may have forgot things.

Comment: @Alex-TinLe As you can see, the Document is not related to the ContestCulture, but to a Culture (didnt designed it and way to late to make architecture changes now :/). So I have to check which `Culture` are used in `ContestCulture` for the `Contest`, then somehow join all of that to check if there is at least one Document for each DocumentType for each ContestCulture...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get the number of document types you need per culture from the `enum`:

```
var numDocumentTypes = Enum.GetNames(typeof(DocumentType)).Length;
```

Then, count the number of distinct document types you have for each `CultureId`:

```
var docTypesPerCulture = documents.GroupBy(d => d.CultureId)
                                  .Select(dg => new {
                                        CultureId = dg.Key,
                                        Count = dg.Select(d => d.DocumentType).Distinct().Count()
                                   });
```

Now, you can left join to the used Culture IDs (to handle Culture IDs that have no documents) and filter to the ones with missing document types:

```
var ans = list_usedCultureIdsForContest.GroupJoin(docTypesPerCulture,
                                                  ci => ci,
                                                  dpc => dpc.CultureId,
                                                  (ci, dpcj) => dpcj.Any() ? dpcj.Select(dpc => new { CultureId = ci, Count = dpc.Count }).Single()
                                                                           : new { CultureId = ci, Count = 0 }
                                        )
                                       .Where(cic => cic.Count != numDocumentTypes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
namespace ConsoleApplication159
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Document> contest = new List<Document>() {
                new Document() { contestCulture = 1,  documentType = DocumentType.Rules },
                new Document() { contestCulture = 1,  documentType = DocumentType.TermsAndConditions },
                new Document() { contestCulture = 1,  documentType = DocumentType.PrivacyPolicy },
                new Document() { contestCulture = 2,  documentType = DocumentType.Rules },
                new Document() { contestCulture = 2,  documentType = DocumentType.TermsAndConditions },
                new Document() { contestCulture = 2,  documentType = DocumentType.PrivacyPolicy  }
            };

            var valid = contest.GroupBy(x => x.contestCulture)
                .Select(x => new { culture = x.Key, valid = Valid(x.ToList()) })
                .ToList();


        }

        static bool Valid(List<Document> documents)
        {
            return documents.Any(x => x.documentType == DocumentType.Rules) &&
                documents.Any(x => x.documentType == DocumentType.TermsAndConditions) &&
                documents.Any(x => x.documentType == DocumentType.PrivacyPolicy);
        }
    }
    public enum DocumentType
    {
        Rules,
        TermsAndConditions,
        PrivacyPolicy
    }
    public class Document
    {
        public int contestCulture { get; set; }
        public DocumentType documentType { get; set; }
    }

}
```

---

And another way

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
namespace ConsoleApplication159
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Document> contest = new List<Document>() {
                new Document() { contestCulture = 1,  documentType = DocumentType.Rules },
                new Document() { contestCulture = 1,  documentType = DocumentType.TermsAndConditions },
                new Document() { contestCulture = 1,  documentType = DocumentType.PrivacyPolicy },
                new Document() { contestCulture = 2,  documentType = DocumentType.Rules },
                new Document() { contestCulture = 2,  documentType = DocumentType.TermsAndConditions },
                new Document() { contestCulture = 2,  documentType = DocumentType.PrivacyPolicy  }
            };

            var valid = contest.GroupBy(x => x.contestCulture)
                .Select(x => new { culture = x.Key, valid = Valid(x.ToList()) })
                .ToList();

        }

        static bool Valid(List<Document> documents)
        {
            int or = 0;
            foreach (Document document in documents)
            {
                or |= (int)document.documentType;
            }
            return (or == 7) ? true : false;
        }
    }
    public enum DocumentType
    {
        Rules = 1,
        TermsAndConditions = 2,
        PrivacyPolicy = 4
    }
    public class Document
    {
        public int contestCulture { get; set; }
        public DocumentType documentType { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. But as i updated the Op, you will see that the Document is not related to the ContestCulture, but to a Culture. It means that I have to get back The ContestCulture and check in the documents if a Document exists for each DocumentType AND for each ContestCulture. But for that I have to somehow join the Culture with ContestCulture... Kinda messed up...

Comment: The culture is not needed to check if the document is valid (3 types).  If you need the name you can do a 2nd query to combine the name with the culture ID.